# JMS serializer deserialize array of numbers

Tags: jms, serialization

I'm using JMS Serializer.
I want to serialize object in number, and deseriazing number in object.
Now I have:

```
Country: { id: 1 }
Countries: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ]
```

But I need to remove this wraps:

```
Country: 1
Countries: [ 1, 2 ]
```

How it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JSON in TextMessage jms objects. It is a more cleaner approach.